# CMake: linking assembly against libc on Linux

Tags: assembly, x86, cmake, libc

I'm trying to learn assembly programming at the moment, and I'm using CMake to build my projects and exercises.

The book I'm following tells me to link one of the example programs with the C standard library using this command line (Programming from the Ground Up, Chapter 8):

```
ld printf-example.o -o printf-example -lc -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

But I'm not sure how to replicate this behaviour from within CMake.

At the moment, my CMake file looks like this:

```
project(ch8)

enable_language(ASM-ATT)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(printf-example printf-example.s)
target_link_libraries(printf-example c)
```

If I leave off the `target_link_libraries` line, `make` fails with 'undefined reference' errors to the libc functions referenced in `printf-example.s`.

If I include the line, `make` succeeds, but when I try to run the program I get the error

```
bash: ./printf-example: No such file or directory
```

`file` gives me this output:

```
printf-example: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), \
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

`uname -m` gives me `i686`, so I don't think I'm linking against the libc for a different architecture.

Does anyone know how to link assembly programs against the C standard library in CMake?

Comment: 1. `ldd` will show what library can't be found. This can help in your diagnostics. 2. Using libc from assembler programs require to use or imitate work of modules used for libc startup (`crti.o`, `crtbegin.o`) and cleanup (`crtn.o`, `crtend.o`), which can be too cumbersome. Instead you could use assembler inside C `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I can get it to work with this statement, but any improvements upon it would be well received.

```
set_target_properties(
    printf-example
    PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "-lc -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2"
)
```